# Repopulate Search string that was submitted in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am searching my database successfully from an input field. i also have pagination set which is also working correctly. once the search is done and results are displayed in my view, my search input field gets empty. i want it to retrieve the value for which it is showing the results. 
i have done this in my project which i found on the internet, i have this in my view

```
 <?php echo form_open('login_controller/search');?>
            <?php echo form_input('search_userinfo',set_value('search_userinfo'),'id="search"'); ?>
            <?php
            $data = array(
                'class' => 'submit',
                'type' => 'submit',
                'content' => '<i class="clip-search-3"></i>'
            );
            echo form_button($data) ;?>
            <?= form_close();?>
```

and i have extended my form helper like this

```
function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
{
if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
{
    if (isset($_POST[$field]))
    {
        return html_escape($_POST[$field], $field);
    }
    if (isset($_GET[$field]))
    {
        return html_escape($_GET[$field], $field);
    }

    return $default;
}

return html_escape($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
}
```

but i am unable to retrieve it in my search field. How can i do that?

Comment: Test your function step by step. Use some `echo` after each `if` statement to see what blocks.